# ¿se puede crear un trigger en mysql insert para dos tablas a la vez con inner join?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy realizando un proyecto en **PHP** y **MySql** donde estoy trabajando la parte de auditoria con trigger, quisiera saber si se puede hacer en un mismo trigger de insert para dos tablas.. anexo aquí el código que estaba probando desde phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TRIGGER Personas_AInsertar AFTER INSERT
FROM personas INNER JOIN usuarios  ON (usuarios.usuarios_cedula=personas.cedula)
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO bitacorapersonas (Accion,fecha,cedUsuario, nombreUsuario,tipoUsuario,cedula,nombreNuevo,apellidoNuevo,sexoNuevo,telefonoNuevo,direccionNuevo,fnacimientoNuevo,usuarioNuevo,correoNuevo) 
VALUES ('Inserto',NOW(),@identificador,@identificador2,@identificador3,NEW.cedula,NEW.nombres,NEW.apellidos,NEW.sexo,NEW.telefono, NEW.direccion,NEW.fnacimiento, NEW.usuario, NEW.correo)
```

los datos de `usuarioNuevo` y `correoNuevo` están en la tabla `usuario` y el resto es en la tabla `personas`. Lo que quiero saber es si en una misma consulta de la la tabla `bitacoraPersona` me pueden salir los campos agregando en una sola fila y no separadas.. los datos que se insertaron de la persona en una linea y los datos de usuario en otra linea.. espero puedan ayudarme

Anexo dos imagenes como me aparecen 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las 2 ultimas acciones que aparecen es de una misma persona, pero la parte de usuario y correo como explique son de un trigger distitnto al del trigger de los datos de la persona, como hago para que aparezca en una misma fila si es de una sola persona?

Comment: el trigger seria de una tabla que hay datos que estan en otra? entendi bien?

Comment: si, en la tabla usuario ya yo tengo un trigger para que me guarde en la tabla bitacora persona el usuario y correo pero me lo separa.. no me lo muestra en una sola linea al momento de insertar un usuario, sino que me los separa

Comment: como que te los separa?? no graba un solo registro? a eso te referis?

Comment: me guarda los dos registros pero por separado y es uno solo

Comment: ¿Podrías hacernos un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? ¿Recuerdas en otras preguntas que te hice un ejemplo en línea para que probaras mis respuesta? Pues algo así, esquema de tablas e inserción datos de ejemplo para ver cómo se produce el efecto que nos cuentas. Te dejo el enlace a uno reciente: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qjC9aVLqim8esGw4niuzeK/1

Comment: @OscarGarcia lo coloque lo mas que pude, como estoy trabajando en php, lo que dice identificador lo  tengo alla, y al momento de ejecutarlo en php me lo guarda todo bien ( como lo mostre en la foto) pero en dos partes separadas https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xk1FXf6LqT9cWJ6baXUC4F/0 por eso preguntaba si se podia hacer un solo trigger pero de ambas tablas para que salga en una sola linea

Comment: No funciona, nada más intentar darle a "Run" me lanza un error de sintaxis dentro de la definición del trigger: `Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'usuario' in 'NEW'`

Comment: @OscarGarcia  cuando lo coloco en DBfiddle me sale errores, que al momento de correrlo por el sistema me hace bien todo, de verdad no se si es porque no se usar el DBFiddle, pero me arroja errores que en el sistema no hace, y en la bitacorapersonas me lo muestra asi como lo coloque en la consulta(en la foto).. de verdad me urge esa parte.. no se si prefieres que te lo pase por otro lado, solo queria saber como hacer un trigger con un inner join para que en una sola consulta de la bitacora saliera el registro de la misma persona y no separados los datos en 2

Comment: ¿Es lo mismo que te sale si haces una exportación en `phpmyadmin` o con `mysqldump`? Algo debe ser diferente porque dice que no existe el campo `usuario` en el `NEW` dentro del trigger de `personas` y es cierto, la tabla `personas` no tiene campo `usuario`.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xk1FXf6LqT9cWJ6baXUC4F/2 @OscarGarcia eso es lo que sale aqui.. y en phpmyadmin no me da error

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64059/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-rodrigo2324).